# allow globstar in sh

Tags: bash, sh

In bash we can do `shopt -s globstar`.

How would I do it in sh? We want to allow commands to work with `**`, e.g. /path/**/*.proto which targets all proto files recursively in /path

Comment: POSIX sh wildcard patterns can't do that. You might be able to make `find` do the job, whatever it is.

Comment: Oh i see. I want to run protoc against all such proto files. So I use find and pipe the result to protoc? do you mind giving it as an example?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `protoc` or how it takes arguments, but maybe something like `find /path -name '*.proto' -exec protoc \{\} +`

Comment: You don't need to escape the braces; `{}` has no special meaning to the shell.

Comment: @chepner Someone *always* has to chirp up about that. I escape the curly braces because that's what the gnu find manpage suggests.

Comment: GNU doesn't even seem to be consistent about that. The page I see in `findutils-4.9` alternates between `{}` and `'{}'`

Comment: @Shawn maybe [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47_17) is more definitive than a gnu manpage?